# How to get the n-th item of a javascript list

Tags: javascript, list

I'm working on something where I need to go through each item of a javascript list by number, get the name AND value of each item, and then do something with that. The list looks like this:

```
{"test-item-1": false, "test-item-2": false, "test-item-3": false}
```

I don't know what order the items will be in though, or even what items there are. So I have to find each item by number. Can anyone help me figure out how to do that?

Comment: What does this list look like?

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag. Are you really talking about JSON (text) here, or about a JavaScript array? Please provide a concrete example of input and expected output.

Comment: What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? What's the expected output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const array = JSON.parse(arrayJSON)
const item = array[n]
```